# SQL Query in VBA code and Access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a problem of syntax ( rror 3134) with my SQL query....
Here is the query :

```
StrSQL1 = "INSERT INTO Repos (Num_utilisateur, Nb_conges_semaine1, Nb_conges_semaine2, Nb_conges_semaine3, Nb_conges_semaine4, Total_conges_mois1, Nb_conges_semaine5, Nb_conges_semaine6, Nb_conges_semaine7, Nb_conges_semaine8, Total_conges_mois2, Nb_conges_semaine9, Nb_conges_semaine10, Nb_conges_semaine11, Nb_conges_semaine12, Total_conges_mois3, Nb_JoursFeries_semaine1, Nb_JoursFeries_semaine2, Nb_JoursFeries_semaine3, Nb_JoursFeries_semaine4, Total_Nb_JoursFeries_mois1, Nb_JoursFeries_semaine5, Nb_JoursFeries_semaine6, Nb_JoursFeries_semaine7, Nb_JoursFeries_semaine8, Total_Nb_JoursFeries_mois2, Nb_JoursFeries_semaine9, Nb_JoursFeries_semaine10, Nb_JoursFeries_semaine11, Nb_JoursFeries_semaine12, Nb_AutresAbsences_semaine1, Nb_AutresAbsences_semaine2, Nb_AutresAbsences_semaine3, Nb_AutresAbsences_semaine4, Total_Nb_AutresAbsences_mois1, Nb_AutresAbsences_semaine5, Nb_AutresAbsences_semaine6, Nb_AutresAbsences_semaine7, Nb_AutresAbsences_semaine8," & _ "# Total_Nb_AutresAbsences_mois2, Nb_AutresAbsences_semaine9, Nb_AutresAbsences_semaine10, Nb_AutresAbsences_semaine11, Nb_AutresAbsences_semaine12, Total_Nb_AutresAbsences_mois3, Total_general) VALUES ('" & NumAgent & "', '" & Conges_1 & "', '" & Conges_2 & "', '" & Conges_3 & "', '" & Conges_4 & "', '" & CongesTotalMois1 & "', '" & Conges_5 & "', '" & Conges_6 & "', '" & Conges_7 & "', '" & Conges_8 & "', '" & CongesTotalMois2 & "', '" & Conges_9 & "', '" & Conges_10 & "', '" & Conges_11 & "', '" & Conges_12 & "', '" & CongesTotalMois3 & "', '" & JourFeriee_1 & "', '" & JourFeriee_2 & "', '" & JourFeriee_3 & "', '" & JourFeriee_4 & "', '" & JourFerieeTotalMois1 & "', '" & JourFeriee_5 & "', '" & JourFeriee_6 & "', '" & JourFeriee_7 & "', '" & JourFeriee_8 & "', '" & JourFerieeTotalMois2 & "', '" & JourFeriee_9 & "', '" & JourFeriee_10 & "', '" & JourFeriee_11 & "', '" & JourFeriee_12 & "', '" & JourFerieeTotalMois3 & "'," & _ "# '" & JourAutre1 & "', '" & JourAutre2 & "', '" & JourAutre3 & "', '" & JourAutre4 & "', '" & JourAutreTotalMois1 & "', '" & JourAutre5 & "', '" & JourAutre6 & "', '" & JourAutre7 & "', '" & JourAutre8 & "', '" & JourAutreTotalMois2 & "', '" & JourAutre9 & "', '" & JourAutre10 & "', '" & JourAutre11 & "', '" & JourAutre12 & "', '" & JourAutreTotalMois3 & "', '" & TotalGeneral & "');"
```

Sorry It's a long query...

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: Show us the processed query.

Answer (score 1):

if i do not see wrong i count 46 fields but 47 values. The number of fields and values must be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your have in  your `INSERT` clause:

```
 # Total_Nb_AutresAbsences_mois2
```

In your `VALUES` clause:

```
#   JourAutre1
```

They're invalid field names.
Try removing the **#** symbol.

**Edit:**
Both @Karthick and @Michelle are correct as you're missing that field in your results.
Also hope I'm correct about the `#` symbol being invalid.